# Relations of Work-Energy to Mass and Distance Without Respect to Time

Tags: forces, energy, work

This may be a stupid question, but is the same amount of energy required to move a body (of mass) a specific distance, with varying forces, as long as it is moved in the same amount of time?

Given $W = F \cdot d$, $F = m \cdot a$, $a = \frac{v}{s}$, and $v = \frac{d}{s}$, the work equation can be rewritten as:

$$W = \frac{m \cdot d^2}{s^2}$$

So this must mean that as long as I move the body the specified distance in the same amount of time, it doesn't matter what forces are applied?

Alternatively, moving a body at a constant velocity will require the same amount of energy as if I had moved the body with constant acceleration, as long as it takes the same amount of time, correct?

Comment: This is only true if the force field is conservative, then the details of how you get from point A to point B do not matter

Comment: What exactly do you mean by force field and conservative? I don't have too much experience in this sort of thing.

Comment: Have you taken some form of calculus?

Comment: Yes, a bit, but only as a senior in high school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So this must mean that as long as I move the body the specified distance in the same amount of time, it doesn't matter what forces are applied?

The equations you have written describe the *average* force, acceleration, etc. It must be that if you move something the same distance in the same amount of time, then the *average* force acting on the body was the same (this all comes from the mean value theorem in calculus). So applying the same force constantly, or applying a larger force but then a smaller force, will give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You have got it all wrong friend we use calculus to derive work done as $F =ma$ and $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$ and $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ so work done in moving the particle $dx$ distance is equal to $m(v\frac{dv}{dx}) dx=mv\cdot dv$ and on integrating it you get $\frac{m}{2}(v_f^2-v_i^2)$.

Here's a derivation:
$$F=ma$$
$$F=m \frac{dv}{dt}$$
$$v=\frac{dx}{dt} \implies dt=\frac{dx}{v}$$
$$F=mv\frac{dv}{dx}$$
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Work} & = \int F\cdot dx \\
 & = \int^{v_f}_{v_{in}}mv\cdot dv \\ 
 & = \frac{m}{2}(v_f^2-v_i^2) 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: If you know v in terms of t then you can solve it further by integrating v with respect to t and thus getting displacement

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please don't post formulae as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial.